# Is there a shortcut to mkdir foo and immediately cd into it?

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal, shortcuts

This is something I do frequently

```
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo
```

This works as a single command, but it's more keystrokes and saves no time.

```
$ mkdir foo && cd foo
```

Is there a shortcut for this?

### Edit

With the use of help below, this seems to be the most elegant answer.

```
# ~/.bashrc
function mkcd {
  if [ ! -n "$1" ]; then
    echo "Enter a directory name"
  elif [ -d $1 ]; then
    echo "\`$1' already exists"
  else
    mkdir $1 && cd $1
  fi
}
```

Comment: You can rename the function to `mkdir` if you use `command mkdir $1` instead of just `mkdir $1` in the function body.

Comment: (1) why not simply "mkdir $1 ; cd $1" instead of "&&"?  that way the "cd" succeeds even if the "mkdir" fails, and you don't need the does-it-already-exist scaffolding. (2) as written your function won't work (to prompt you for a directory name).  you need to put that in a separate "if" clause from the existence test (currently in "elif").

Comment: Or even `mkdir -p $1; cd $1` so you can make nested directories and move into them. @quackquixote

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I'm no Linux/bash expert, but try putting this in your `.bashrc`.

```
function mkdir
{
  command mkdir $1 && cd $1
}
```

PS Thanks to Dennis for using `command mkdir`.

Comment: Instead of `\`which mkdir\``, just use `command mkdir`.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. There's nothing under `man command` - could you direct me to a reference? (I can work out what it does, but it pays to be thorough;)

Comment: `command` is described in **the manual of `bash`** (which it is a built-in of; it's not a separate command). You could also try **`help command`**.

Comment: That also works for zsh btw

Comment: Bad idea to overload the usual mkdir and to change its behavior. A lot of scripts use it and assume there is no change of the current directory. Better is to define a command with a different name.

Answer (score 118):

### The `bash`, `zsh` Shells

If you don't want another function to remember and don't mind bashisms:

```
$ mkdir /home/foo/doc/bar && cd $_
```

The `$_` (dollar underscore) bash command variable contains the most recent parameter.  So if a user were to type the following at the command line: `echo foo bar && echo $_ baz`, then the output would be as follows:

```
foo bar
bar baz
```

### The `fish` Shell

In the fish shell, I would type the following:

```
> mkdir /home/foo/doc/bar
> cd alt + ↑
```

The alt key combined with either the up or the down arrow key will cycle through command parameter history.

Comment: This works in `zsh` too.

Comment: Can you explain what $_ is? Newbie here.

Comment: @NabilKadimi Did you mean that <kbd>Alt<kbd>+<kbd>⬆<kbd> works well in Zsh?
Actually, with zsh 5.4.2 and on-my-zsh, Alt+⬆ gives me character 'A'.

Comment: Put `$_` in quotes as in `"$_"`.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I don't use Bourne derived shells. Too many foot guns.

Comment: I have decided to call `$_` as the 'dollar short' variable, colloquially.

Comment: Does this need a `-p` option? For zsh in OSX I needed it.

Answer (score 48):

For *oh-my-zsh* users:
`$ take 'directory_name'`

Reference: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Cheatsheet

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail?

Comment: @bwDraco `type take`, then you will get `take is a shell function from /home/username/.oh-my-zsh/lib/functions.zsh`. vi the file then you get `function take() {
   mkdir -p $@ && cd ${@:$#}
 }`

Answer (score 12):

What about:

```
$ mkdir newdirname; cd $_
```

It's a bit easier than using &&, combining quack quixote's and kzh's answers.

Comment: The point of `&&` is that `cd` will not be executed if the `mkdir` command fails

Comment: @slhck actually that was the point of quixote: cd even if mkdir fails (for instance if it already exists, forcing the user to write a second command to actually cd to the path). However contrarily to what this answers says, that's not for easiness: && is not more complicated than ;.

Answer (score 8):

You can try something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir $1 && cd $1
```

Save this script to some place that is in your path, for example, /usr/local/bin or ~/bin (you have to put this last one into your path in your ~/.profile file). Then you can simply call it.

Comment: how can this work? it seems to only `cd` inside the context of the execution of the `~/bin/mkcd` script, not the caller of the script.

Answer (score 6):

```
$echo 'mkcd() { mkdir -p "$@" && cd "$_"; }' >> ~/.bashrc
$mkcd < pathtofolder/foldername >
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple function I put in my `~/.config/fish/config.fish` file which accomplishes this task:

```
function mkcd
    mkdir -pv $argv;
    cd $argv;
end
```

The `-pv` tag allows for the creation of directories with sub-directories.

Answer (score 1):

If you use zsh there is a cool shortcut:

`take <Your_folder_name>`

and it will create a folder and change to it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the desired outcome if the directory already exists.

**Fail if directory already exists**

```
mkcd() {
    mkdir $1 && cd $1
}
```

**Change directory regardless**

```
mkcd() {
    mkdir $1 ; cd $1
}
```

**Usage**
mkcd some/path/to/my/dir

Answer (score 0):

I found that the function below can only make one directory, if I want to make subdirectories at the same time, it doesn't work :

```
function mkdir
{
  command mkdir $1 && cd $1
}
```

So I changed it and now its working great!

```
function mkcd
{
  command mkdir -pv $1 && cd $1 && echo "Now in `pwd`"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For **[bash](/questions/tagged/bash)** **[macos](/questions/tagged/macos)** this is the only way it worked for me

```
function md
{
  command mkdir -vp $1 && command cd $1 && echo "Now in `pwd`"
}
```